# How to arrange the Amount,Debit,Credit and balance in 1 row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to arrange my query into single  row (1 row  per cdvno, amount , debit , credit and balance)
however  i cant arrange them . Into 1 single row

sample codes

```
select a.cdvno,b.Amount, a.debit, a.credit, a.credit + a.debit - coalesce(b.amount,0) as balance
from (
    select cdvno, debit, sum(credit) credit, trantype
    from cdvdtl  
    where debit = 0
    group by cdvno, debit, trantype
    union all
    select cdvno, sum(debit) debit, credit, trantype
    from cdvdtl  
    where credit = 0
    group by cdvno, credit, trantype
) a
left join cdvhdr b
    on b.cdvno = a.cdvno
    and b.trantype = a.trantype
where  a.credit + a.debit - coalesce(b.amount,0) <> 0
order by a.cdvno
```

results

```
cdvno               Amount      debit     credit    balance
000-2016-01000004   25137.50    25326.16    0.00    188.66
000-2016-01000004   25137.50    0.00    25326.16    188.66
000-2016-01000005   15849.90    0.00    16010.00    160.10
000-2016-01000005   15849.90    16010.00    0.00    160.10
000-2016-01000007   217938.73   0.00    220006.50   2067.77
000-2016-01000007   217938.73   220006.50   0.00    2067.77
```

I tried(sum)amount but it doesn't work. I Want the result if possible to be like this

```
cdvno             Amount        debit       credit      balance
000-2016-01000004   25137.5     25326.16    25326.16    188.66
000-2016-01000005   15849.9     16010       16010       160.1
000-2016-01000007   217938.73   220006.5    220006.5    2067.77
```

Thank you so much I know this is so simple for you guys but for me Im stuck in here :D newbee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ignore the `union` (that's causing to create separate entries for debit and `credit`) and use `select case` instead.

```
select a.cdvno,b.Amount
    , a.debit
    , a.credit
    , coalesce(b.amount,0) - coalesce(a.debit, a.credit) as balance
from (
    select cdvno
        , sum(case when credit = 0 then debit else 0 end) as debit
        , sum(case when debit = 0 then credit else 0 end) credit
        , trantype
    from cdvdtl    
    group by cdvno, trantype    
) a 
left join cdvhdr b
     on b.cdvno = a.cdvno and b.trantype = a.trantype
where  a.credit + a.debit - coalesce(b.amount,0) <> 0
    order by a.`cdvno`
```

Comment: it works hahah But like always I dont know what happen sensie , Enlighten me. How does the sum ( case) works ?

Comment: @raphaelestranero, actually, it tried to create separate row for debit and credit, so nag carry during left join

Comment: @metal what happen to the balance  , the math doesn't follow

Comment: @raphaelestranero, try again

Comment: @metal, how does this function works coalesce(b.amount,0) - coalesce(a.debit, a.credit). If my understanding is correct b.amount will minus itself to the debit and the credit ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want aggregation conditional aggregation.  This would make sense to me:

```
select d.cdvno,
       sum(case when d.credit = 0 then d.debit end) as debit,
       sum(case when d.debit = 0 then d.credit end) as credit,
       (h.amount +
        sum(case when d.debit = 0 then d.credit end) -
        sum(case when d.credit = 0 then d.debit end)
       ) as balance
from cdvdtl d join
     cdvhdr h
     on h.cdvno = d.cdvno and h.trantype = d.trantype
group by d.cdvno, h.amount
order by d.cdvno;
```

Note the use of the table aliases.  Instead of arbitrary letters, these are abbreviations for the table names.

Comment: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'cdvhdr.CDVNo' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. ERROR on that I dont understand sensie :D

Comment: @raphaelestranero . . . That should be `cdvno` -- which I've changed.  It is valid because it is an aggregation key.